# Typesafe Hetereogeneous Container design pattern with typesafe collections as value

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections, type-safety

I want to create a typesafe collection which can store multiple collections of the same type but with typesafe parameters. The standart way:

```
Map<Key<?>, Object> container = new HashMap<>();
```

The key contains the type of the object and the get method casts to the correct type (standart typesafe hetereogeneous container pattern). But i need something like this:

```
container.put(Key, new HashMap<Long, String>);
```

The type itself would be safe (Map.class) but i don't know how to ensure that key and value of the map are of the type long and string. How can i do that with java?

**EDIT**

To make things clearer:

```
Map<Class<?>, Object> container = new HashMap<>();
```

Now the typesafe implementation of this map:

```
public <T> void put(Class<T> key, T value) {
    container.put(key, value);
  }

  public <T> T get(Class<T> key) {
    return key.cast(container.get(key));
  }
```

I can to this in a typesafe way now:

```
containerClass.put(Double.class, 2.0);
containerClass.put(Integer.class, 3);
```

And of course:

```
containerClass.put(MyObject.class, myObject);
```

If i want to store multiple values of the same type than i could use a generic list instead of the object as a value or a specific key class which has an identifier as a field.

**BUT**

What happens now?

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
containerClass.put(Map.class, map);
```

With this implementation it is not safe that it is a map with String as a key and integer as the value. I want to store all kinds of objects and collections but the collections itself must be typesafe too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your Key class is but the following is perhaps what you are looking for, just replace String with your Key class

```
    Map<String, Map<? extends Long, ? extends String>> container = new HashMap<>();
    container.put("", new HashMap<Long, String>());
    container.put("", new HashMap<Long, Long>());
```

if you try to compile that code, you will find the first put is okay but the 2nd will not compile due to non compliance to the Map type. That type states only an object that extends Long is accepted as the 1st parameter and the 2nd only accepts objects that extend String.

Comment: The problem here is that the value of the map must be of the type map. I want the typicall typesafe hetereogeneous container pattern. So I want to be able to put all kinds of datatypes into that map but also Lists or Maps as a value. I want to ensure that the possible map i use as a value is typesafe itself.

Comment: I am confused now, too many maps. Which map value must be of type map? If you mean that your map<Key<?>, Object> value, i.e. Object must be of type Map, then what I gave you does that as Map<? extends Long, ? extends String> constrains Object to a Map type keyed on Long with a String value, which is what you wanted and as such will accept any Object that implements Map with the specified genereic types. If not then perhaps you could explain a bit clearer which map value must be of type Map?

Comment: Since both `Long` and `String` are final, `? extends` doesn't really make much of a difference.

Comment: They just constrain the map type to Long and String nothing more, which is what was intended.